# disable unix extensions per share in samba

Tags: samba

I created a share which needs

`follow symlinks = yes`

`wide links = yes`

Is it possible to disable the unix extensions just for this share or enable following links without global

`unix extensions = no`?

Comment: Not only link to documentation would be great, but also to source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the `smb.conf` [manual page](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html), `unix extensions` is a [global parameter](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#UNIXEXTENSIONS) - you cannot set it per share.

By default `wide links` (a per-share parameter) is disabled if `unix extensions` is enabled, but you can disable the link between the two options by using the `allow insecure wide links` option:

> Setting allow insecure wide links to true disables the link between these two parameters, removing this protection and allowing a site to configure the server to follow symlinks (by setting wide links to "true") even when unix extensions is turned on.

I think that should give you what you want.